# ¿Como validar form vacio laravel?

Tags: laravel, validación

Tengo una duda con respecto a las validaciones, basicamente lo que busco es que si existe por lo menos un solo elemento en el request permita pasar la vadilacion, pero si todos los atributos estan vacios devuelva error.

Sinceramente soy un poco nuevo en el uso de laravel y no se me ocurre mas que recorrer el request pero no sabria como mostrar los mensajes de error

```
public function rules()
{
dd($this->validationData()); // Contiene los datos recibidos del cliente
return [
  'comment' => 'string|min:8|max:300',
  'rating' => 'integer|between:1,5'
];
```

}

En el request encontre los datos pero no se como retornaria el error

Comment: en el controller puedes hacer un `  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),//rules ); if($validator->fails()){//erro!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que pudieras proceder así:

- Emplea el método [`hasAny`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input) para identificar si cualquiera de los elementos pasados en el array existen en el `$request`

  ```
  if ($request->hasAny['elemento1', 'elementoN']) {
      /*Proceso de validacion*/
  }
  ```
- El método anterior retorna `true` en caso de ser así y es en este punto donde construyes tu validador
- A tu validador deberás indicarle que los valores pueden ser [`nullables`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) así:

  ```
  'elemento' => 'nullable'
  ```
- Dado el punto anterior entonces deberás retirar la regla de `required`
- Para el caso de los mensajes de error puedes entonces mostrarlos,  [iterando el array **`$errors->all()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) dentro de tu vista

Comment: Probe con el metodo hasAny y por alguna extraña razon no me funciona cuando envio objetos `JSON`, Hice las pruebas con postam y cuando envio los datos mediante `x-www-form-urlencoded` o `form-data` funciona 100 de 100, cosa que no pasa con objetos `JSON`, que es la forma mas probable de como se envien los datos desde el frontend

Comment: Es decir ¿si aplicas esto excepto con json no funciona, pero en otros casos si?

Comment: Sali y apague el pc, ahora que retomo funciona perfectamente... aun no se porque suceda y ante todo gracias que si encuentro algo estare informando xD

Comment: Si para que publiques la solución y así nos enteramos como se resuelve

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que utilice siguiendo las sigerencias de BetaM aplicado al aarchivo request es el siguiente:

`use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

```
public function rules()
{
 $contains = $this->validationData();
 $contains = Arr::hasAny($contains, ['item1', 'item2', '...']);
 if ($contains) {
  return [
   'item1' => 'nullable|rules',
   'item2' => 'nullable|rules',
   '...'   => 'nullable|rules'
  ];
 } else {
  return [
   'items' => 'required'
  ];
 }
}
```

En el else se puede colocar un mensaje personalizado y listo... funciona!!!